# What is the difference between [0-9]{3} and [0-9]<space>{3} in RegEx?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a file -

```
cat regex30.txt 
(914).582.3013
(873).334.2589
(521).589.3147
(625).235.3698
(895).568.2145
(745).256.3369
```

I want to convert this to

```
914.582.3013
873.334.2589
521.589.3147
625.235.3698
895.568.2145
745.256.3369
```

Here are my steps -

```
sed -r 's/\(([0-9]<Space>{3})\)(\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4})/\1\2/g' regex30.txt
```

then I get the result -

```
(914).582.3013
(873).334.2589
(521).589.3147
(625).235.3698
(895).568.2145
(745).256.3369
```

Why I get that result? How come space matters there?

If I remove space then it works correctly.

```
sed -r 's/\(([0-9]{3})\)(\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4})/\1\2/g' regex30.txt 
914.582.3013
873.334.2589
521.589.3147
625.235.3698
895.568.2145
745.256.3369
```

My understanding is that `[0-9] {3}` -- means 3 digit numbers, it can
start with zero as well.

What is the difference between `[0-9]{3}` and `[0-9] {3}` in RegEx?

Why space matters there or is it something I am unable to see all together.

I thought '\s' is used to represent spaces.

Comment: Space is also a token in regular expression. That's why no substitution is done, as you provided the information.

Comment: If you just want to delete parentheses, use `tr -d '()' <indata`,

Comment: I thought /s is used to represent space.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I did not try to parse your regular expression. Here is the answer to your question.

`[0-9]{3}` means exactly three decimal digits. `[0-9] {3}` means a single decimal digit followed by exactly three spaces. This is so because `{3}` (which is a so-called "bound") repeats the so-called "atom" preceding it.

From the regex manual page:

```
$ man regex
... An atom followed by a bound containing one integer i and no comma 
matches a sequence of exactly i matches of the atom. ...
```

The term "atom" is defined in the following paragraph. Great reading.

Comment: Technically, `[0-9]` is 3 *collating elements* that sort in between 0 and 9. While that *includes* ASCII decimal digit *characters*, in several `sed` implementations (including GNU `sed`) and some locales, that includes a lot more.

Comment: @Stéphane so GNU treats `[0-9]` as being equivalent to `[[:digit:]]`? Meaning that if I really want just Latin digits I have to write an ERE such as `(0|1|3|...|9)`? Or would forcing the C locale be sufficient still?

Comment: @roaima, no `[[:digit:]]` is meant to match on `[0123456789]` though in practice on some systems (not GNU AFAIK) it matches on other decimal digits (in other numeral systems). `[0-9]` can match on things that are not digits, they just need to sort in between 0 and 9. That could be for instance  or . It's also likely not to include digits 9 in other numeral systems/scripts as they would likely come after ASCII `9`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you

Comment: @roaima, in the C locale `[0-9]` and `[0123456789]` are equivalent but changing `LC_CTYPE` to `C` changes the way sequences of bytes are interpreted into characters. In some charsets, the encoding of 0-9 also appear as part of some other characters so `LC_ALL=C grep '[0-9]'` could for instance match inside some characters if the input was encoded in charsets such as GB18030 (the charset used in some Chinese locales) for instance.

Comment: @roaima, see details at [what is the meaning of this shell script function](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/616167)

Comment: I thought /s is used to represent space.

Answer (score 1):

The only regexps that I know where white space can be ignored are the perl ones or compatible and the ast-open ones (which did borrow many operators from perl regexps), though that's not done by default, only when the `x` flag is enabled.

AFAIK, only `ssed` supports PCREs with the -R option.

So you'd need:

```
ssed -R 's/ \d {3}/.../gx'
ssed -R 's/(?x) \d {3}/.../g'
```

Or (ast-open `sed`, which also is the `sed` builtin of ksh93 if enabled):

```
ast-sed    's/\(?x\) \d \{3\}/.../g'
ast-sed -E 's/(?x) \d {3}/.../g'
ast-sed -A 's/(?x) \d {3}/.../g'
```

(for the 3 flavours of regexp it supports: basic, extended, augmented).

When the `x` flag is enabled, to match a literal space character, you need `[ ]` or prefix the space with `\` (or use `\x20` on ASCII based systems).

Comment: I thought /s is used to represent space.

Comment: @tannoyconnect `\s` (not `/s`) is the nonstandard equivalent of `[[:space:]]` which matches on any character classified as whitespace like tab, or space. That's even more characters than `[[:blank:]]`/`\h` in that it also includes vertical whitespace like cr, lf, vt, ff.